# double scrollbars on resizing with maximize and restore browser-window

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have the following situation:

I've got a header, content, and a footer.

Now the header and footer have a fixed height and are always on the screen.

css for footer and header:

```
#footer {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
    width:100%;
    height:46px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    border-top:1px solid #7F8C8D;
    z-index:101;
}


#header {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#828282;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:105;
    width:100%;

    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

As for the content i have the following:

```
#content {
    background: #9cbbe3 url(../img/backgr.gif) repeat-x;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background-size:auto;
    position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;     
}
```

Now this works! at first...

But then i go and maximize and minimize the window, and i end up with two scroll-bars.
When i refresh the page the problem is fixed. and re-sizing works as far as I've noticed. but when maximizing and restoring the window i end up with two scroll-bars.

How can i solve this preferably using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works out for you:

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Sorry it appeared to be a caching problem of some sort i think. for some reason it all works now. cleared the cache enough times but this time i deleted everything i had, which did the trick. my bad.

Though i had a couple of pages left that kept giving me a scrollbar over the entire page when it wasnt neccesairy and this solved that problem. so i'll mark it since it might help some people to get rid of the second scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

```
overflow: auto;
```

to:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Hi, this solves the double scroll-bars however the scrollbar now appears to go over the header and footer and not just in the content when maximizing->restoring the window. after refreshing the scrollbar appears only in the content like i wanted.
so this solves the double scrollbar problem but the scrollbar is in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry was adjusting the wrong css i get the following result:
when minimizing->maximizing this causes the scroll-bar to appear over the header and footer. on refresh this causes the scroll-bar to disapear entirely.

Also yes jsFiddle does sound helpful but i was wondering if there isn't a clean CSS solution for this problem.

Comment: Markup is also important and we can't see any of that, hence why I asked for a fiddle :)

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you meant injecting javascript in my page to get it right. i'll get on it!

Comment: Sorry it appeared to be a caching problem of some sort i think. for some reason it all works now. cleared the cache enough times but this time i deleted everything i had, which did the trick. my bad. +1 for the help though.